# Rotated TouchableOpacity crashes on Android when selected

Tags: android, react-native, touchableopacity, react-native-stylesheet

I rotate a `TouchableOpacity` (**without any animation**) as this:

```
transform: [
  { rotate: '45deg' }
]
```

It works fine on iOS, but crashes on Android (*see tested versions below*):

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double

I can't put a Double on `rotate`, as I get a *Invariant violation*. What can I do?

---

Environment :

- OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13.5
- Node: 7.10.0
- Yarn: 1.9.4
- npm: 4.2.0
- Watchman: 4.9.0
- Xcode: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
- Android Studio: 3.2 AI-181.5540.7.32.5014246

Packages:(wanted => installed)

- react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1
- react-native: 0.55.1 => 0.55.1

Tested on:

- iOS 12 (worked fine on device and simulator)
- Android 7.0 and 8.1 (both device and emulator)

[Direct reference to this issue on Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19931)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally use radians with `Platform`, they'll get converted to double without error:

```
import {Platform} from 'react-native'
…
transform: [
  {rotate: (Platform.OS === 'ios') ? '45deg' : (3.14159/4)+'rad'}
]
```

This will then display fine.

**But, that rotated TouchableOpacity loses its touchable behavior by the way.**

To fix this, use a child view to apply your rotation on :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={…}>
  <View style={styles.yourRotation}>
     …
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magic Answer**
You can rotate View instead TouchableOpacity. Change same width and height separately

```
<TouchableOpacity  style={{  height: 100, width: 20 }} >
                <View style={{  height: 20, width: 100, transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }] }}>
                       <Text>PRESS</Text>
                </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```